# Error introduced by rounding values from a continuous distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, bias, discrete-data

I am implementing a sampling routine to sample from a discrete normal distribution. I use a standard technique for sampling from continuous normal distribution and then round my values. If I am rounding values from a continuous normal distribution, how much error does the rounding introduce in the distribution while discretizing?  I have researched through to find methods to estimate the statistical distance between the 2 distributions (the one I generate and the discrete normal) and I have also learnt that the way the rounding is done also accounts for the error.  The rounding I do is standard rounding procedure (ex: >=0.5 to 1 and <0.5 to 0) .

I used Matlab to make histograms and do the KS test to check if my discrete distribution is normal and the results suggests that it is.  But, is there a way I can theoretically estimate the statistical distance between the discrete distribution I am generating and the discrete normal?

Comment: There is more than one meaning of "discrete normal distribution."  Rounding the continuous one [is one possible definition](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/178964/estimating-the-variance-of-a-discrete-normal-distribution).   Another approach obtains a Normal-like distribution supported on the integers by [maximizing the entropy given the mean and variance](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378375897000207). Is this what you mean by "discrete normal"? And why are you testing whether samples from your distribution appear "normal"? That seems irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I need samples from the discrete normal for my application. So, I have to verify that the samples I get are actually from discrete normal. I am looking at the discrete normal defined by the distribution function: D_{Z,sigma} (x) = f(x)/S, where f(x) = e^(-x^2/2(sigma)^2) and S = sum_{-infinity}^{infinity} f(x). And, I need to measure the distance between the distribution from my implementation and the discrete normal by this definition.

Comment: I am also not sure if the way the rounding is done affects the distribution. For example, if I round in a way that 0.5 goes to 0 and -0.5 goes to -1 and so on, rounding always to the left, How do I know how much different is that distribution from the distribution I get when I round 0.5 to 1 and -0.5 to -1.

Comment: If your definition of a discrete normal distribution is that it is a rounded normal distribution, and you simulate it by first simulating a normal, then rounding, you are using the exact definition in the simulation procedure, so there should be no need of testing?